# how to find all documents in MongoDB between HH:mm format time using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query a mongoose model by the documents start time, the documet has an "activeTimes" field which is an array of objects,
each object have 3 keys: **weekday**, **startTime**, **endTime**

Schema example:

```
const classSchema = new Schema({
    activeTime: [{
        weekday: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 6
     },
     startTime: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     },
     endTime: {
       type: String,
       required: true
     }
   }]
 });
```

I wish to query the model and find all the documents that are between 12:00 and 15:00... but since i'm using a HH:mm format it seems that mongoose isn't able to fetch the correct results...

is there a way to query this correctly?

note: i can't save the dates at their full format because the class is repeated every week based on the `weekday` property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - Querying between a time range of hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17834596/mongodb-querying-between-a-time-range-of-hours)

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet the given question uses a Date object type, I'm using string type... technically not a duplicate

Comment: Then you should save it as `timeOfDay` as mentioned in the second answer. Saving a time as string is not a best way and even you cannot query with the string time either `(HH:mm)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to compare your wanted time-strings with the $lte or $gte operator, since the format of the fields is consistent and $gt and $lte on strings just does a lexicographical comparison. Look here for more info: http://technotip.com/4101/string-comparison-mongodb/

Still, for logical and performance reasons (that's what I write, when I am talking about code-smell) I would recommend you split the startTime and endTime from a '00:00' string into an either an object like this:

```
startTime: {
 hour: Number,
 minute: Number,
 required: true //note that {} would also be a valid value unless you make hour and minute required separately
}
```

or

```
startTime [Number, Number] // where startTime[0] is the hour and startTime[1] is the minute
```

If you have only even times e.g. 15:00 or 12:00, it'll be easy to query for that, because you can then query this the same way you would query for a date, using the $gte and the $lte operator. If you have to include the minutes, it could look something like this:

e.g.:

```
Class.find(
 { 'startTime.hour': {$gte: 12},
 { 'startTime.minute': {$gte: 0},
 { 'endTime.hour': {$lte: 15},
 { 'endTime.minute': {$gte: 0},
)
```

Note: You'll have to adapt this more, since it currently also returns values like endTime: 15:59.

Comment: Hi,
Eventually I represented the time as an array, thank you!