# Mongodb query to calculate and compare time by number of seconds since midnight

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find records that were created between a say 2:00pm and 4:0pm.  I am not concerned about the date fields just the time.  I am currently breaking the date/time to just time in terms of number of seconds since midnight.  The issue is that the query does not seem to be pulling any records.

Here is the query:

```
db.getCollection("test1").aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      testHour: { $hour: "$createdAt" },
      testMinute: { $minute: "$createdAt" },
      testSecond: { $second: "$createdAt" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      testSeconds: {
        $add: [
          { $multiply: ["$testHour", 3600] },
          { $multiply: ["$testMinute", 60] },
          { $multiply: ["$testSecond", 1] }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [{ testSeconds: { $gte: 7200 } }, { testSeconds: { $lte: 14400 } }]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } }
]);
```

I am not returning any records in my results.  Am I missing something in this query?  I even tried to set the range between 1 and 86400, but this did not work either.

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427356/4368485) for an optimal way to query on hours